# Objective-C set bundle setting value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, settings-bundle

I created a bundle setting for my app with these options:

and now I have this class called LHTabBarController.m

and I am trying to get the value of Update Lot like so:

Item 1 (Toggle Switch - Update Lot) - Type - Toggle Switch, Title - Update Lot, Identifier - update_lot, Value for ON - YES, Value for OFF - NO, Default Value - YES

```
BOOL updateLot = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"update_lot"];
```

but no matter what it returns as NO when the default is YES....what am I doing wrong here?

In the bundle settings, the setting is on as expected, but I can't seem to get that value. I hope I don't have to do this in AppDelegate because I need to use this value in my class.

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey:` with `NSUserDefaults`. And besides, you can't assign the result of `valueForKey:` to a `BOOL` variable. Don't ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: And keep in mind that the default values set in a Settings bundle will not appear in returned values from `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `boolForKey` instead:

```
BOOL updateLot = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"update_lot"];
```

[Foundation Framework Reference >  NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/boolForKey:)